# JavaScript Object Literal and jQuery $(classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I have an object that contains a list of browser widths

```
breakpoints {
    smallMobile: 0, 
    mobile: 480, 
    tablet: 672, 
    desktop: 868, 
    largeDesktop: 1050
}
```

I want to add a class to the `body` of the document based on whether the browser width falls between two values in the breakpoints object.

#### What I have so far

```
var key;

for (key in breakpoints) {
    if (breakpoints.hasOwnProperty(key))
        if (winWidth >= breakpoints[key]) {
            $('body').removeClass().addClass(key);
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works, however it also removes ALL classes from the `body`. Instead I would like to add only one class, and not have to remove anything unless the breakpoint no longer matches.

I'm sure there has to be a way. Any help would be appreciated :)

#### EDIT

Current output at various widths

>= 1050: `<body class="smallMobile mobile tablet desktop largeDesktop">`

>= 868: `<body class="smallMobile mobile tablet desktop">`

>= 672: `<body class="smallMobile mobile tablet">`

Ideal output

>= 1050: `<body class="largeDesktop">`

>= 868: `<body class="desktop">`

>= 672: `<body class="tablet">`

(For the record I use Media Queries, but I need access to classnames for an edge case)

Comment: Keep a reference to the original body classes, `document.body.classList`, and play around with your breakpoints without altering the others.

Comment: Have you considered using media queries instead? You can apply CSS based on the dimension of the viewport. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've slightly modified your code and saved the class thats the highest applicable one. Then I remove every class and apply the applicable one.

```
// create a variable to store the only class you want to apply
var apply = "";
for (var key in breakpoints) {
    // keep overwriting the apply var if the new key is applicable
    if (winWidth >= breakpoints[key]) {
       apply = key;
    }
    // remove any existing classes with that keyname
    $('body').removeClass(key);
}
// add the key to the body as a class
$('body').addClass(apply);
```

Also, you can remove `breakpoints.hasOwnProperty(key)` as the `for`-loop only loops through keys that actually exist anyway, so you are doing an unnecessary check.

#### Update

At @juvian's note, I'll add a way to make sure that the order in which you make your object makes no difference:

```
var apply = "";
var check = 0;
for (var key in breakpoints) {
    // Also check if the value is higher than the last set value
    if (winWidth >= breakpoints[key] && breakpoints[key] >= check) {
        apply = key;
        check = breakpoints[key];
    }
    $('body').removeClass(key);
}
$('body').addClass(apply);
```

Comment: This works as long as the values from the keys are in  ascending order

Comment: Boom. Hero. This works exactly as I wanted. For everyone else, thank you! For the record, I am using Media Queries but I have an odd edge case where I need classes in both the JS and CSS and it's easier than doing an if/else block in the JS to check.

Comment: @juvian, they are. I am always order things in ascending and I will be the only one with the code :)

Comment: Yeah can be easily changed, just wanted to point out for future users ;)

Comment: @juvian I added the code for looping through them out of order. Hope that helps future generations (:

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using removeClass() without any parameter in it.

> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will
>   be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are
>   specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

So, you should find the right class to remove and then call this function with a param.

Comment: If you tell him to remove all the other classes first and  then add the correct class, I'll +1 you. Just so he can add only the correct class but leave other classes intact.

Comment: @somethinghere That's exactly what I said. When I said "Find the right class to remove" I thought, he might have other classes in body which is not related to this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to store your breakpoints in sorted array instead of map:

```
var dimensions = [];
for (var key in breakpoints) {
   dimensions.push({ name: key, width: breakpoints[key] })
}

dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return b.width - a.width });
```

Now dimensions is

```
[
    {"name":"largeDesktop","width":1050},
    {"name":"desktop","width":868},
    {"name":"tablet","width":672},
    {"name":"mobile","width":480},
    {"name":"smallMobile","width":0}
]
```

Of course you can hardcode it in this structure and not grep/sort each time.

Finally, find highest width with

```
for (var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) {
    if (winWidth >= dimensions[i].width) {
        $("body").addClass(dimensions[i].name);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if you want to create responsive layout, media queries is the way to go. Media queries also will take windows resize/orientation change events into account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can get the one that matches with the highest value:

```
var wid = 868;
var max = 0;
var size = null;

Object.keys(breakpoints).map(function(a){
    size = wid >= breakpoints[a] ? a : size;
    max = wid >= breakpoints[a] ? Math.max(max,breakpoints[a]) : max;
})
console.log(max, size) // 868, 'desktop'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use .removeClass() without parameter then all class on selected element will remove as like prabu said, but if you want, i give some example so you will not confused how to remove class if window width less than breakpoints

```
var key;
for (key in breakpoints) { 
    if (breakpoints.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $("body").addClass(key);
        if (winWidth<breakpoints[key]) {
            $("body").removeClass(key);
        }
    }
}
```